# Small problem at equation solving

Tags: equation-solving

I have $2$ equations in $2$ parameters which involve integrations. The limits of the integrals can not be defined analytically. They also require equation solving and eventually I couldnt incorporate everything in a nice way to solve. Here is my code

**density functions**

```
f0[y_] :=1/(E^((1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
f1[y_] :=1/(E^((-1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
```

**likelihood function**

```
l[y]=E^(-(-1 + y)^2/2 + (1 + y)^2/2)
```

**inverse of the likelihood function**

```
ll[y_] :=Log[y]/2
```

The integral limits $yu$ and $yl$ which I have problems with, where $λ0$ and $μ0$ are some parameters.

```
FindRoot[l[yu] == Sqrt[(λ0*(λ0 + μ0*f1[yu]))/(λ0*(λ0 + (μ0 - 1)*f0[yu]))], {yu, 3}]
FindRoot[l[yl] == Sqrt[(λ0*(λ0 + (μ0 - 1)*f1[yl]))/(λ0*(λ0 + μ0*f0[yl]))], {yl, 3}]
```

Whenever $λ0$ and $μ0$ are known it is easy to find a solution for $yu$ and $yl$

%% my $2$ equations are as follows

```
h1[y_] :=Integrate[-2 + Sqrt[λ0/(λ0 + (-1 + μ0)*f0[y])] + Sqrt[(λ0 +(-1 + μ0)*f0[y])/λ0], {y, yu, Infinity}] +Integrate[-2 + Sqrt[λ0/(λ0 + μ0*f0[y])] + Sqrt[(λ0 + μ0*f0[y])/λ0], {y, -Infinity, yl}] + Integrate[-2 + Sqrt[(f1[y]*(λ0*f0[y] + λ0*f1[y]))/(f0[y]*(λ0*f1[y] + f0[y]*(λ0 + (-1 + μ0 + μ0)*f1[y])))] + Sqrt[(f0[y]*(λ0*f1[y] + f0[y]*(λ0 + (-1 + μ0 + μ0)*f1[y])))/(f1[y]*(λ0*f0[y] + λ0*f1[y]))], {y, yl, yu}]

h3[y_]:=Integrate[Sqrt[(λ0*f0[y]^2)/(λ0 + (-1 + μ0)*f0[y])], {y, yu, Infinity}] + Integrate[Sqrt[(λ0*f0[y]^2)/(λ0 + μ0*f0[y])], {y, -Infinity, yl}] + Integrate[Sqrt[(f0[y]*f1[y]*(λ0*f0[y] + λ0*f1[y]))/(λ0*f1[y] + f0[y]*(λ0 + (-1 + μ0 + μ0)*f1[y]))], {y, yl, yu}]
```

I am using `Findroot` to solve them as follows:

```
FindRoot[{h1[y] == 0.08, h3[y] == 1}, {{μ0, 0.4}, {λ0, 0.8}}, 
         StepMonitor :> Print["Step to μ0 = ", μ0]]
```

as one can see $h1$ and $h3$ involve $yl$ and $yu$ which are the solution of another equations. These equations can only be numerically evaluated. At this point my eventual aim is to solve the last `FindRoot` of my code.

In simple words if I would be *Mathematica* I would guess some $λ0$ and $μ0$ then I would go to the first $2$  `FindRoots` of my code solve them and get $yl$ and $yu$ numerically.

Then using these values I would obtain $h1$ and $h3$ and eventually I would go to last `FindRoot` of my code to see if $h1=0.08$ and $h3=1$ are satisfied or not.

If not I would change $λ0$ and $μ0$ until the equations are satisfied. This is of course the worst way of solving the equations but *Mathematica* would have a better way I suppose.

How should I modify my code such that *Mathematica* could start solving them? The equations are horrible and will take at any case alot of time.

Thanks for reading my problems and for any help.

Comment: You have an undefined lambda1 and mu1 in h1 and h3

Comment: @belisarius my apologies $μ1:=μ0$ and $λ1:=λ0$ I just corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many errors to describe each one of them separately.

I'll post a working code below, but you should try to learn how to solve problems with Mathematica one step at a time. You had thrown in too much non-working code and your debugging will be always a nightmare programming like that.

```
f0[y_] := 1/(E^((1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
f1[y_] := 1/(E^((-1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
l[y_] := E^(-(-1 + y)^2/2 + (1 + y)^2/2)
opts = {Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> None}, AccuracyGoal -> 8};

yueq[λ0_?NumericQ, μ0_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[l[yu] == Sqrt[(λ0*(λ0 + μ0* f1[yu]))/
                                                           (λ0*(λ0 + (μ0 - 1)* f0[yu]))], {yu, 3}]
yleq[λ0_?NumericQ, μ0_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[l[yl] == Sqrt[(λ0*(λ0 + (μ0 - 1)* f1[yl]))/
                                                          (λ0*(λ0 + μ0*f0[yl]))], {yl, 3}]

h1[λ0_?NumericQ, μ0_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[-2 + Sqrt[λ0/(λ0 + (-1 + μ0)*f0[y])] + Sqrt[(λ0 + (-1 + μ0)*f0[y])/λ0], 
                                 {y, yu /. yueq[λ0, μ0], Infinity}, Evaluate@opts] +
  NIntegrate[-2 + Sqrt[λ0/(λ0 + μ0*f0[y])] + Sqrt[(λ0 + μ0*f0[y])/λ0], 
                                 {y, -Infinity, yl /. yleq[λ0, μ0]}, Evaluate@opts] + 
  NIntegrate[-2 + Sqrt[(f1[y]*(λ0*f0[y] + λ0*f1[y]))/(f0[y]*(λ0*f1[y] + 
                       f0[y]*(λ0 + (-1 + μ0 + μ0)*f1[y])))] + 
                  Sqrt[(f0[y]*(λ0*f1[y] + f0[y]*(λ0 + (-1 + μ0 + μ0)*f1[y])))/
                       (f1[y]*(λ0*f0[y] + λ0*f1[y]))], 
                                   {y, yl /. yleq[λ0, μ0], yu /. yueq[λ0, μ0]}, Evaluate@opts]

h3[λ0_?NumericQ, μ0_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[ Sqrt[(λ0*f0[y]^2)/(λ0 + (-1 + μ0)*f0[y])], 
                                    {y, yu /. yueq[λ0, μ0], Infinity}, Evaluate@opts] + 
  NIntegrate[Sqrt[(λ0* f0[y]^2)/(λ0 + μ0*f0[y])], 
                                    {y, -Infinity, yl /. yleq[λ0, μ0]}, Evaluate@opts] + 
  NIntegrate[Sqrt[(f0[y]* f1[y]*(λ0*f0[y] + λ0*f1[y]))/(λ0* f1[y] + f0[y]*(λ0 + (-1 + μ0 + μ0)*f1[y]))],
                                     {y, yl /. yleq[λ0, μ0], yu /. yueq[λ0, μ0]}, 
   Evaluate@opts]

sol = FindRoot[{h1[λ0, μ0] == 0.08, h3[λ0, μ0] == 1}, {{μ0, 0.4}, {λ0, 0.8}}, 
               StepMonitor :> Print["Step to μ0 = ", μ0]]

(*
 {μ0 -> 0.125521 - 6.10413*10^-22 I, λ0 -> 0.286823 + 2.85401*10^-23 I}
*)
```

Comment: that is very nice of you. I will read it tomorrow carefully and let you know what I learned. You are right. My codes are not so nice.

Comment: it is really great and so fast! What I learned is that if I will not use symbolic things then I should better turn it off and the accuracygoal is also important. I think both factors make the code fast. I guess symbolic thing has higher impact of the speed of the code? I also understood that whenever I have equations to solve and there are some other parameters which can be found analytically I can state them inside findroot with "/." I also learned Evaluate@... so to use the reasonable options. I also havent understood yet the meaning of "μ0_?" the question marking.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Glad it helped. See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html.

Comment: thanks again I checked it. For all $\mu 0$ which is numeric the expression becomes true. Is it used to restrict the search to numerical values?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören It's used to restraint the use of symbolic processing, which may give exact results but will cost you processing time and/or errors if the symbolic results can't be obtained

Comment: okay so Evaluate@opts alone is not enough to guarrantee that the solutions are done only on the non analytic domain. If so then I can use all the tricks here whenever I wont need symbolic processing.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Well, you may check that. Perhaps I over-protected the symbolic processing. Try removing the `?NumericQs` and see what happens